# How do I get the height and width of the Android Navigation Bar programmatically in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

How do I get the height and width of this UI element in pixel?

[image: How do I get the height and width of this UI element in pixel?]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use this to get the bottom nav bar height

```
MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom
```

Comment: Both MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom and MediaQuery.of(context).padding.bottom returns 0.0 for me...

Comment: wrong answer. this is how find keyboard is open or not

Comment: This doesn't work on Pixel 3a API 30 emulator, always returns 0.

Answer (score 6):

The following works for me:

```
final double navigationBarHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).padding.bottom
```

Answer (score 2):

If

```dart
final double navigationBarHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).padding.bottom
```

doesn't work, check if you are not calling this inside

> SafeArea, a widget that consumes this padding with a Padding widget and automatically removes it from the MediaQuery for its child.